# Following Amazon Product page links while Parsing using PHP

Tags: php, parsing, dom, simple-html-dom

I wrote a PHP script to scrape the product review page links of amazon products. However, am having trouble navigating through pages of products. [Amazon displays only 12 products per pages].

My script utilizes the Simple HTML Dom Parser.

This is a part of my script that follows the link to the next page of products:

```
 if($nextPage=$html->find('#pagnNextLink',-1)) {
    $next = "http://amazon.com".$nextPage->href;

  // This works: 
// $next = "http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_2/179-2481337-1920701?rh=n%3A2625373011%2Cn%3A%212625374011%2Cn%3A2649512011%2Cp_n_date%3A2693527011%2Cp_n_theme_browse-bin%3A2650365011%2Cp_n_format_browse-bin%3A2650305011&page=2&ie=UTF8&qid=1372370539";

    echo "<p>".$next;


   getProducts($next);
}
```

The problem: 
    The base page which was initially loaded to the function keeps getting loaded and the next page link which was found in the current page is not visited.

However the commented line works in the above snippet. :\ 
Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, but wondering why this doesn't work ?

Comment: doesn't matter Amazon’s Terms and Conditions explicitly forbid web scraping tools.

Comment: because it's a different url?

Answer (score 0):

your `id` is wrong

```
<a title="Next Page" id="pagnNextLink" class="pagnNext" href="/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Atoothbrush&amp;page=2&amp;keywords=toothbrush&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1372374734">
            <span id="pagnNextString">Next Page</span>
            <span class="srSprite pagnNextArrow"></span>
         </a>
```

the proper id should be `#pageNextLink`

Comment: its _pagnNextLink_ only. Check :)